# Big Commerce Formatting - I Need Text Fields in a Row

Tags: text, formatting, field, row, bigcommerce

I don't have much experience with Big Commerce.  We've been trying for weeks to accomplish what should be very simple.

We have five text fields, for a customer to enter their eyewear prescription, and our customer wants them in one row.  BigCommerce displays them as five rows in one column.  I've experimented with the html templates and the css, I've searched here and Google, etc.  I haven't figured out how to isolate the individual fields in order to format them.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use a web inspection tool like firebug or the built-in developer tools in firefox, and hover over the text boxes you want to format. That should tell you a class you can target.

The class of your input element is something like "Field validation productAttributeFluidWidth"